# How to instead of update?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make an instead of update trigger on my table. For now the trigger works but because it is an instead of, it will not perform the normal update to the table.

What do I need to add an instead of update trigger to perform the regular update after my Code?

Comment: Do you mean an `AFTER INSERT` trigger?

Comment: no, I ned to do something before the update is applied. So I thought that I need a instead of update trigger, add my Code there and than do the Default update handling.

Comment: You only have 2 options of triggers in SQL Server, `AFTER` or `INSTEAD OF`. There is no `BEFORE`. If you need to use an `INSTEAD OF` you need to handle every part of the insert (as, as the name suggests, the logic of the trigger is used, instead of that of a "normal" insert).

Comment: Nope, if you're doing an instead of trigger, it's up to *you* to perform the required changes to the tables. You said "out of the way, I'm taking over" - so carry on and complete your job.

Comment: Or write a stored procedure that does what you want, then grant execute on that procedure, but not update on the table.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I dont know what the table usually does if a row gets updatet. Do I have to remove the row and add it back in from inserted?

Comment: Just issue an [`UPDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks-for-dml-triggers): "If an INSTEAD OF trigger defined on a table executes a statement against the table that would ordinarily fire the INSTEAD OF trigger again, the trigger is not called recursively. Instead, the statement is processed as if the table had no INSTEAD OF trigger and starts the chain of constraint operations and AFTER trigger executions"

Comment: Google is very helpful... https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1804/using-instead-of-triggers-in-sql-server-for-dml-operations/